# Console access of paper.js objects

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, paperjs

Im using Paper.js to make some diagrams and do not have access to any of the objects or methods in the console in google chrome. My code is running fine and is in a script tag:

```
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">            
            var path = new Path();
            path.strokeColor = 'black'
</script>
```

and in chrome console:

```
 ReferenceError: path is not defined;
            etc...
```

Is there any way to get to this to work so I can prototype easier?

Comment: You need to provide your example as a link that someone can have a more in-depth look. Because what you have here should not give an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PaperScripts run in their own scope, so they are not exposed to the global scope and thus cannot that simply be inspected in the console (See [Paper.js Interoperability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439046/paper-js-interoperability/26083149#26083149)).

But what you can do is set a simple `debugger;` statement in your code, which will trigger the debugger. There you will be able to inspect the item:

```
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">            
    var path = new Path();
    path.strokeColor = 'black';
    debugger;
</script>
```